# NSUserDefaults not loading in IOS4

Tags: cocoa, loading, nsuserdefaults

I have an app that was written under OS 3.x - it worked fine back then.
Since rebuilding for OS 4.1 it no longer works with regard to loading the app settings.

I have a 'root.plist' file bundled with the app. Some of the default settings are already set in there by editing the file, i.e. hostname, timeout, etc. A new user must supply some login credentials so these are left blank. When the app starts for the first time, it detects the missing credentials and shuts down, asking the user to go to Settings and enter credentials.
If I open settings, I see what I expect; a hostname, timeout and other defaults as they were in root.plist. I enter the username and password, plus one other ID code.
When I restart the app, I get values back for the data I just keyed in, plus the BOOL protocolswitch = YES (which I did not change). The other values all return nil, despite appearing in settings.

```
username   = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"name_preference"];
password   = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password_preference"];
CRMID      =  [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userID_preference"]uppercaseString] retain];
hostname   = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"hostname_preference"];
protocolSwitch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"http_preference"];
timeout    = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"timeout_preference"];
portNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"port_preference"];
bccEmail   = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"bcc_email_preference"];
locationOn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"location_preference"];
```

I know about "synchronize" but I'm not actually changing these values from within my app, so I don't see how that applies here. I've also made sure the app isn't running in background before restarting, makes no difference.
It worked perfectly before OS4, does anyone understand the change in behaviour? Any way to fix it?
Cheers,

Sarge62.

There is definitely something wrong with the Settings result.
Having dumped the dictionary keys to console when the app launches, I see this:

> ```
> "location_preference",
> NSInterfaceStyle,
> AppleLanguages,
> "userID_preference",
> AppleKeyboardsExpanded,
> AppleLocale,
> AppleKeyboards,
> NSLanguages,
> "http_preference",
> "password_preference",
> "name_preference"
> ```

There are only five of the keys defined in the plist!
If I go to settings and change the hostname to something other than what was in the plist default, it will appear in the log above.
It seems that there is a bug(?) in the Settings screen that only registers keys that are changed from the initial default value (for string objects at least, BOOLS are OK).

Comment: happened to me too, started falling back to the 'pre-packaged' defaults dictionary when nil is encountered

Comment: just submitted a Bug ID# 9908757 about it

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered the defaults ? This is done typically in a `+ (void) initialize` class method of the app delegate.

for example

```
+ (void)initialize {
NSMutableDictionary *defaultValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[defaultValues setObject:@"defaultHostname" forKey:@"hostname"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultValues];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gorilla, but I don't think it's that. I know what you mean - I have some other code in a 4.1 app that does this - it reads the root.plist file and writes the content of that dictionary back if it determines that the defaults don't exist.

Comment: Not so sure if it is behaving odd. To my knowledge NSUserDefaults only saves preferences which are different from the default values which you registered. This would fit to your observation, too.